# Is there any way to stream videos in Discord.py?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, video-streaming, bots, discord.py

Good morning!

I was looking for a way to stream videos through a discord bot, but couldn't find any references in the documentation. Is there any way (official/unofficial) to do this?
Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Hmm, you would have to use a user token and not a bot token. It's quite likely you will have to do this, since you will come upon the bot-API often, however this isn't documentated, so you will have to play with your browser dev tools and reverse engineer the backend for the stream API. Once you've done that, it's just matter of implementing it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## No, bots cannot stream.

There is this [support discussion](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360059238512-Add-Go-Live-support-for-API), a [github issue](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/1386) and a [github discussion](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/discussions/3234)

There have been several comments about this from Discord staff in the Discord API server:

[image: video sharing is sufficiently hard that i dont think any bot implementation would be able to get it right] and
[image: we won't be supporting video for bots]
Mind you, this comes from a discord staff
[image: proof]

And there's also [this GitHub issue comment](https://github.com/discord/discord-api-docs/issues/1995#issuecomment-678550660) by the same staff:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Such a shame :(